# What does if <command>; [ $? = 4 ]; then <...> do?

Tags: bash, if-statement, conditional-statements

I stumbled upon this snippet of code and asked myself about it's significance:

```
if `getopt -T >/dev/null 2>&1` ; [ $? = 4 ]
then
#do a thing 
else
#do the other thing
fi
```

What irritates me is the [ $? = 4 ] part. It looks like a test for the exit code of the last command which would make sense since "#do a thing" and "#do the other thing" relate to how to deal with different versions of getopt, but is it even evaluated? If so, how? I have never seen such a statement after the if keyword.

Thanks!

Comment: That's *extremely* silly code. It could just be `if getopt -T >/dev/null 2>&1; [ $? = 4 ]; then` without the backticks and it would be precisely equivalent (except substantially more efficient).

Comment: And although such a thing is rare, it's exactly *why* the keyword `then` is required. A semicolon alone simply separates two commands in the *list* that forms the condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's review the output of `help if`:

> ```
> if: if COMMANDS; then COMMANDS; [ elif COMMANDS; then COMMANDS; ]... [ else COMMANDS; ] fi
>    The `if COMMANDS' list is executed.  If its exit status is zero, then the
>    `then COMMANDS' list is executed.  Otherwise, each `elif COMMANDS' list is
>    executed in turn, and if its exit status is zero, the corresponding
>    `then COMMANDS' list is executed and the if command completes.  Otherwise,
>    the `else COMMANDS' list is executed, if present.  The exit status of the
>    entire construct is the exit status of the last command executed, or zero
>    if no condition tested true.
> ```

---

In light of the above, consider the following:

- `if COMMANDS; then ...` notably accepts `COMMANDS` -- a list, which can consist of multiple commands combined by separators.
- `foo; bar` is a command list which runs both `foo` and `bar`; when it's complete, the exit status of the compound command is that of `bar`.
- `[ $? = 4 ]` tests whether the immediately preceding program's exit status is exactly 4.
- `getopt -T >/dev/null 2>&1; [ $? = 4 ]` thus tests whether `getopt -T` exits with a status of precisely 4.

Thus, your code runs the `#do a thing` block if `getopt -T` fails with exit status 4, and `#do the other thing` otherwise.

Comment: I did not consider this! Thank you!